# Laravel parent/child relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mariadb, eloquent-relationship

I have the following db table that has a corresponding model inside my laravel app.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Comments (
  handle           varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  parent_handle    varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  comment_topic    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  user_id          bigint(20)   NOT NULL,
  comment_body     longtext     NOT NULL,
  depth            int(11)      NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  created_at       timestamp    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at       timestamp    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  deleted_at       timestamp    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (handle),
  KEY user_id_key(user_id),
  CONSTRAINT comments_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Parent child relationships are nestable via handle-parent_handle relationships. That means:

```
handle   | parent_handle | user_id | comment                                 | depth
---------|---------------|---------|-----------------------------------------|-------------
handle1  | null          | 3       | this is the first comment               | 1
handle2  | handle1       | 2       | this is a reply to the first comment    | 2
handle3  | null          | 4       | this is a new top level comment         | 1
handle4  | handle2       | 3       | this is a reply to handle2              | 3
handle5  | handle4       | 4       | this is a reply to handle4              | 4
handle6  | handle2       | 1       | this is also a reply to handle2         | 3
handle7  | handle5       | 3       | this is a reply to handle5              | 5
handle8  | handle7       | 4       | reply to handle7                        | 6
```

I want to be able to get back a nested result. Therefore I'm using the following CTE to get back the nested relationships.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE NestedComments AS (
    SELECT handle, comment_body, user_id, parent_handle, created_at, depth
      FROM Comments WHERE topic = 'topicid1' AND parent_handle IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.handle, c.comment_body, c.user_id, c.parent_handle, c.created_at, depth
      FROM Comments AS c
INNER JOIN NestedComments AS nc
        ON c.parent_handle = nc.handle
)
    SELECT NC.handle, NC.parent_handle, NC.comment_body, NC.created_at, NC.depth, U.username
      FROM NestedComments AS NC
INNER JOIN Users AS U 
        ON U.id = NC.user_id
     WHERE NC.depth <= 3
  ORDER BY NC.created_at;
```

My problem is that I want to transform the above to the following json result:

```json
{
  "object": "comment",
  "handle": "handle1"
  "user": [
    "username": "jsmith",
    "display_name": "John Smith",
  ],
  "body": "this is the first comment",
  "reply_count": 5,
  "replies": [{
      "object": "comment",
      "handle": "handle2"
      "user": [
         "username": "dsmith",
         "display_name": "Dan Smith",
      ],
      "body": "this is a reply to the first comment",
      "reply_count": 2,
      "replies": [{
          "object": "comment",
          "handle": "handle4"
          "user": [
             "username": "jsmith",
             "display_name": "John Smith",
          ],
          "body": "this is a reply to handle2",
          "reply_count": 3,
          "replies": []
         }, {
          "object": "comment",
          "handle": "handle6",
          "user": [
             "username": "JAsmith",
             "display_name": "Jacklyn Smith",
          ],
          "body": "this is also a reply to handle2",
          "reply_count": 0,
          "replies": []
        }
      ]}
   ]
}, {
  "object": "comment",
  "handle": "handle3",
  "user": [
    "username": "jesmith",
    "display_name": "Jenny Smith",
  ],
  "body": "this is a new top level comment",
  "reply_count": 0,
  "replies": []
}
```

I do have the Parent and Replies eloquent relationships defined

```php
final public function Parent() : HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Comments::class, 'handle', 'parent_handle');
}

final public function Replies() : HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'parent_handle', 'handle');
}
```

But I have no idea how to adjust it so that I get the json response I require.

Comment: Try with eager loading like `$data = Comment::with('user')->get();`

Comment: @STA Yeah but how would I get replies nested inside replies until I hit depth $n. Also I need to count how many replies each object may or may not have nested inside the replies object.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list

Comment: @MaartenVeerman thanks that's actually pretty helpful.